# Prove that if the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges for $x = x_0$, then it converges absolutely for all $x$ such that $|x| <|x_0|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, absolute-convergence

> Prove that if the power series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges for $x = x_0$, then it converges absolutely for all $x$ such that $|x| <|x_0|$.

I am supposed to use the following corollary to the Root Test to prove the above prompt:

> **COROLLARY**: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then,
>
> (a) if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 0$, then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges absolutely for all real $x$.
>
> (b) if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = L > 0$, then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges absolutely for $|x| <{1\over L}$ and diverges for $|x| > {1 \over L}$.
>
> (c) if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \infty$, then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges only for $x = 0$.

Here is my attempt at proving the prompt:

**PROOF:**

For (a), if we suppose that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 0$, then by the **corollary**, we know that the power series converges absolutely for all real $x$, and by extension converges for all $x$ such that $|x| < |x_0|$.

For (b), if we suppose that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = L > 0$, note that from the Root Test, we have that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_nx_0^n|} = |x_0|\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = |x_0|L < 1 \implies |x_0| < {1\over L},$$ since the power series is to converge when $x = x_0$. Hence for all real $x$ such that $|x| < |x_0|$, by the **corollary**, $|x| < |x_0| < {1\over L}$ gives us that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ will converge absolutely for all such $x$.

For (c), if $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \infty$, we know by the **corollary** that the power series will converge *only* for $x=0$ and the result is therefore trivial since there exists no $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $|x| < |x_0| = 0$. Thus we are done.

**Here's my question:** I'm a little confused as to if I really proved anything at all in (c). It seems like I encountered an impossibility rather than proved the prompt. Did I make a mistake here (or anywhere else for that matter)?

Comment: The hypothesis must include that it converges *absolutely* for $x=x_0$; or that $x_0>0$. Counter example: the *alternating harmonic series*.

Comment: $\sum a_nx_0^n$ converging doesn't imply $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|a_nx_o^n\right|}<1$. Consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $x_0=1$.

Comment: Just use the fact that if $\sum a_nx_0^n$ converges, then the sequence $\left|a_nx_0^n\right|$ is bouded. So for $\left|x\right|<\left|x_0\right|$, $\left|a_nx^n\right|=\left|a_nx_0^n\right|\left|\frac{x}{x_0}\right|^n$ is the product of a bounded sequence and a convergent geometric sequence, hence the absolute convergence.

Comment: @Bernard : no, you're wrong in this case. Just look at my proof :-)

Comment: @Nicolas FRANCOIS: You're right. I read `<` as `≤`.

Answer (score 1):

Your above proof is correct.

FRED

Comment: No it is not, IMHO.